# backspace error in asm input string routine

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, osdev

I'm writing an OS in asm and I'm trying to implement the MikeOS input string routine. When I run it, it works well the only thing is that I can only backspace one character, then it doesn't backspace anymore. Here is the code:

```
; ------------------------------------------------------------------

; os_input_string --- Get a string from keyboard input

; IN: AX = output address, BX = maximum bytes of output string
; OUT: nothing

os_input_string:
    
    pusha

    ; If the character count is zero, don't do anything.
    cmp bx, 0
    je .done

    mov di, ax          ; DI = Current position in buffer
    
    dec bx              ; BX = Maximum characters in string
    mov cx, bx          ; CX = Remaining character count

.get_char:

    call _getkey

    cmp al, 8
    je .backspace

    cmp al, 13          ; The ENTER key ends the prompt
    je .end_string

    ; Do not add any characters if the maximum size has been reached.

    jcxz .get_char

    ; Only add printable characters (ASCII Values 32-126)
    cmp al, ' '
    jb .get_char

    cmp al, 126
    ja .get_char

    call .add_char

    dec cx
    jmp .get_char

.end_string:

    mov al, 0
    stosb

.done:

    popa
    ret

.backspace:

    ; Check if there are any characters to backspace
    cmp cx, bx 
    jge .get_char

    inc cx              ; Increase characters remaining

    call .reverse_cursor        ; Move back to the previous character
    mov al, ' '         ; Print a space on the character
    call .add_char
    call .reverse_cursor        ; Now move the cursor back again

    jmp .get_char

.reverse_cursor:

    dec di              ; Move the output pointer backwards
    
    call _get_cursor_pos
    cmp dl, 1           ; Is the cursor at the start of line?
    je .back_line

    dec dl              ; If not, just decrease the column
    call _set_cursor
    ret

.back_line:

    dec dh              ; Otherwise, move the cursor to the end
    mov dl, 79          ; of the previous line.
    call _set_cursor
    ret


.add_char:

    stosb
    mov ah, 0x0E            ; Teletype Function
    push bx
    mov bh, 0           ; Video Page 0
    push bp             ; Some BIOS's may mess up BP
    int 0x10
    pop bp
    pop bx
    ret
```

here's _get_cursor_pos

```
_get_cursor_pos:

    push bx
    mov ah, 03h
    mov bh, 0
    int 10h
    pop bx
    ret
```

here's _set_cursor

```
    _set_cursor:
    pusha
    mov bh, 00

    mov ah, 2
    int 10h
    popa
    ret
```

Comment: What does happen when you try to backspace again?  When you single-step it with a debugger (e.g. the one built-in to Bochs), what instructions are executing?

Comment: So I can backspace once, then never again. So say I input "abcdefg" and want to backspace "fg", I can only backspace "g"  and then it won't let me backspace ever again (unless I reset the VM)

Comment: When you single-step with a debugger and look at what instruction is executing, and values in registers, what do you see?  Your code is not very minimal ([mcve]), so you should definitely do some debugging to narrow down what might be going on.

Comment: I'm using QEMU, not Bochs. QEMU (correct me if I'm wrong) does not have a debugger

Comment: QEMU can act as a target for GDB remote debugging.  I'd recommend Bochs, but if you're not messing around much with segmentation then GDB-remote attached to QEMU should be fine.  Trying to learn asm without a debugger is a waste of your time (and everyone else's).

Answer (score 2):

### Backspace messes with your variables

When you retrieve the cursor position, you inadvertently modify the `CX` register that holds your *remaining characters count*. See the description of this BIOS function [GetCursorPositionAndConfiguration](http://www.techhelpmanual.com/118-int_10h_03h__query_cursor_position_and_size.html).

You can't use `pusha` and `popa` for your *_get_cursor_pos* (like you did for the *_set_cursor* code), because you need to return the `DX` register. Use next code that allows `AX` to get trashed:

```
; IN () OUT (dx) MOD (ax)
_get_cursor_pos:
    push bx
    push cx
    mov  bh, 0
    mov  ah, 03h
    int  10h     ; -> CX, DX
    pop  cx
    pop  bx
    ret

; IN (dx) OUT () MOD (ax)
_set_cursor_pos:
    push bx
    mov  bh, 0
    mov  ah, 02h
    int  10h
    pop  bx
    ret
```

### A small additional problem

> ```
> cmp dl, 1           ; Is the cursor at the start of line?
> je .back_line
> ```

The cursor column ranges from **0** to **79** on the 80x25 text screen. Testing for being at the start of the line needs to compare with **0**.

The below code not only corrects the mistake, it also streamlines the procedure:

```
.reverse_cursor:
  dec  di              ; Move the output pointer backwards
  call _get_cursor_pos ; -> DL DH
  dec  dl              ; This DEC turns negative if the cursor was at the left
  jns  .SetCursor      ; If that happens, fall through in .back_line
.back_line:
  dec dh               ; Otherwise, move the cursor to the end
  mov dl, 79           ; of the previous line.
.SetCursor:
  jmp _set_cursor
```

Comment: `jns  .SetCursor` could of course be `jns  _set_cursor`, so that path of execution just directly tailcalls, instead of jumping to another jmp.  (Especially if it's in range for a `jcc rel8` to reach, otherwise this saves a couple bytes, or more with workarounds for pre-386 jcc near)